# How long does it take for a white dwarf to undergo a type Ia supernova?

Tags: supernova, white-dwarf, explosion

I read about white dwarfs and their relation to Type Ia supernovae, and I want to know how much time passes between when the white dwarf passes the Chandrasekhar limit and when the white dwarf explodes. So is there an exact value of this time, or does it vary between these events?

Comment: Currently, we believe that a SN Ia come from interacting between a WD and another object. By accreting materials onto the WD, this triggers SN. To predict how long for a WD in its binary interaction to go SN, there are several factors. We do not understand well about the distribution of this system, therefore I don't think there is an answer for this question.

Comment: @KornpobBhirombhakdi I am asking about how long does it take between the WD exceeding the Chandrasekhar limit and the time it undergoes SN Ia, not the time from formation of the dwarf to SN Ia.

Comment: Like how long since its exceeding the Chandrasekhar limit until it actually explodes?

Comment: @KornpobBhirombhakdi Yes

Comment: From what Wikipedia provides, it is about 1s from a simulation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_Ia_supernova